# Combining Queries into one Display Line in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

The relevant (greatly abbreviated) part of my SQL:

```
Select 
A.Client_ID,
,CASE
  WHEN FN.FLD_CD = 1
  THEN
      FN.AMOUNT
      ELSE
      NULL
  END AS "LN1"
,CASE
  WHEN FN.FLD_CD = 2
  THEN
       FN.AMOUNT
      ELSE
      NULL
  END AS "LN2"
,CASE
  WHEN FN.FLD_CD = 3
  THEN
      FN.AMOUNT
      ELSE
      NULL
  END AS "LN3"
  (...and so on)
  FROM
  ASSESSMENT A,
  FINANCE FN
  WHERE
   A.CLIENT_ID     = FN.CLIENT_ID
   AND FN.FLD_CD IN ( '1', '2', '3')
   (other irrelevant stuff)
   ;
```

This displays the results from the Query on 3 separate lines (one for each field code). How do I get it to display all on one line?

For example, the Results are:

```
Client_ID   LN1    LN2     LN3
10001       20     -       -
10001       -      30      -
10001       -      -       40
```

but I would like it like this:

```
Client ID   LN1    LN2   LN3
10001       20     30    40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  Assuming one value per client per code:

```
SELECT A.Client_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FN.FLD_CD = 1 THEN FN.AMOUNT END) as LN1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FN.FLD_CD = 2 THEN FN.AMOUNT END) as LN2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN FN.FLD_CD = 3 THEN FN.AMOUNT END) as LN3
FROM ASSESSMENT A JOIN
     FINANCE FN
     ON A.CLIENT_ID = FN.CLIENT_ID
WHERE FN.FLD_CD IN ('1', '2', '3')
   (other irrelevant stuff)
GROUP BY A.CLIENT_ID;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- The solution to your query is the `GROUP BY` clause along with the aggregation functions in the `SELECT` clause.
- You might want `SUM()` instead of `MAX()` if multiple codes exist with the same value for a client.
- As the query is written, you don't need a `JOIN` (just use `f.CLIENT_ID` for the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  I assume the `JOIN` is needed for other stuff not in the query.